# increase max upload limit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to upload a PDF file to my *wordpress site*. When I go to **Upload New Media**, and try uploading it, it says

> FileName.pdf exceeds the maximum upload size for this site.

I tried looking for my php.ini file but could not find it. I ran `phpinfo()` by creating a new file and then opening it in my browser and found this.

> ```
> Configuration File (php.ini) Path 
> C:\Windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File 
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php.ini
> ```

I placed a php.ini files with

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 300
```

in wp-admin, httpdocs and everywhere I had access, nothing worked The max upload file size is just 8 MB. Please help me, My client needs to upload that file.

Note: Please don't tell me to restart server, as I can't, It is a hosted site.

Comment: make sure you run phpinfo on your hosted server, not locally..

Comment: Well, php.ini changes will not go into effect until you restart the server, so...

Comment: you can't just dump .ini files everywhere. PHP by default only looks in a couple places for them.

Comment: Yes I ran it on server where my webpages are running.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with the following plugin:

```php
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Increase Upload Limit */

add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'b5f_increase_upload' );

function b5f_increase_upload( $bytes )
{
    return 33554432; // 32 megabytes
}
```

I built this code based on the following [core function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/media.php#L1155):

```php
function wp_max_upload_size() {
    $u_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'upload_max_filesize' ) );
    $p_bytes = wp_convert_hr_to_bytes( ini_get( 'post_max_size' ) );
    $bytes   = apply_filters( 'upload_size_limit', min( $u_bytes, $p_bytes ), $u_bytes, $p_bytes );
    return $bytes;
}
```

Another option is upload via FTP and use the plugin [Add from Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/).

Comment: I don't know much about php, I am into C#, Can you please tell me where do I put this code?

Comment: Only the first part of the code. Create a PHP file, paste it. Upload to `wp-content/plugins/increase-upload-limit/YOUR-FILE.php`. Activate.

Comment: You are great! Thanks, this did the trick. I think I just created a plugin with your help. Thanks.

Comment: Although this seems simple, I would love to know what is the logic? Can you please explain?

Comment: This is [using hooks](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/) with the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). The basics of [plugin development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pagesize=50) ;)

Comment: I still get an **HTTP Error** right after the uploading reaches 100%. Any clues?

Comment: Maybe the execution time.. Any [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) information?

Comment: I fixed it by installing an Uploader plugin.

Comment: This is just genius . on some hosts all other methods fail !

Comment: ABSOLUTELY PERFECT! I successfully applied it to CherryFramework custom theme in custom-function.php (includes/custom-function.php)

Comment: @brasofilo the error could be due to this Error "filename"
The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I'm limited to 64MB so I added this code to my function then added a zero to the value but I'm still limited to 64MB.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was editing the php.ini file at

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

and adding/editing the following options starting (**~ line 786**):

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried different way like attempted to

1. change my limit directly on my server
2. through the .htaccess file
3. wp-config.php

but none of these changes worked for me. Then I came across a post somewhere That I summarised in a blog post(find below)

All you need to do is

1. create a php.ini
2. upload to admin directory

Your Php.ini may contain following or whatever limit you need

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been adding php.ini to the root as well as the uploads folder with no luck. It was wp-admin that requires the file!

Answer (score 2):

WHM/CPanel users Only

I have been struggling with this for a while now, I found the most simple way to solve this to login to your WHM > PHP Configuration Editor > Change (upload_max_filesize) then hit "SAVE".

This makes a change to your server's php.ini file (the simple way).

Answer (score 2):

I'm running WHM / cPanel on a CloudLinux based server. I tried everything. The final solution for me was adding a php.ini file to the /wp-admin/ directory with the following;

```
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Keep in mind I previously tried a php.ini in the document root and the web root directories and those didn't fix the max upload limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're on hosted service, try adding these to your .htaccess file as well:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
```

You won't be able to change these via ini_set();

Comment: Where can I find the .htaccess file?

Comment: If you don't have one, you'll need to create one. Pretty sure that Wordpress already has a .htaccess file in the main public root though?

Comment: No I don't have it there.. What do you suggest now?

Comment: You could create one.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal, go to Settings -> Permlinks and hit `Update`, this will create the file.

Comment: @brasofilo: I did that, no file is created.

Comment: How do I create one and where?

Comment: Using filezilla, I was able to ftp into my server and the file was under WWW. Modified and worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to cPanel users only. I'm not sure about which versions of cPanel it will work with, but it works with the version 56.0.33.

Login to cPanel > Select PHP version > Switch To PHP Options > Click the greyed out number next to upload_max_filesize > Change > Save

I believe this makes a change to the server's php.ini file.

Comment: I found on my cPanel as "MultiPHP INI Editor " with basic options to edit. Most of other suggested methods didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have written php.ini file properly. Just mention path of your php.ini file inside .htaccess file using suPHP_ConfigPath/home/username/public_html. Here replace username with your username mentioned in cpanel. You can refer http://www.vinaypn.com/how-to-fix-maximum-upload-size-exceeded-error-in-wordpress-running-on-shared-hosting/