# HTTP Error on large file upload in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have looked for this problem's solution everywhere but nothing seems to be working.
I get HTTP Error while uploading a file (PDF) with size around 10 MB. I also tried uploading another PDF with size 4 MB and it got uploaded at once. No issues.

Note: I have increased the default upload file size limit to 32 MB by using the custom plugin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751779/increase-max-upload-limit-in-wordpress/17751995?noredirect=1#17751995)

Please suggest me what to do. I do not have any php.ini and .htaccess. And I have no support from my hosting provider. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

once check your php configuration

```
post_max_size  & upload_max_filesize
```

Check upload settings

```
/wp-admin/settings.php
```

Comment: I don't have a php.ini file anywhere. Let me check the settings.php file also.

Comment: if you are on shared hosting you need to contact your hosting provider, if you are on dedicated hosting you will find php config in easy apache WHM

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause was plugin All In One WP Security an its "Basic Firewall Settings". The above firewall features are applied via your .htaccess file and one if these features is "Limit file upload size (10MB)."

So to make upload of files larger then 10 MB working again you can do following:

1) Go to WP Security / Firewall / Basic firewall rules tab and uncheck "Enable Basic Firewall Protection". Then Save settings. This will disable all Basic firewall settings and this 10 MB upload limitation as well.

or

2) If you want to keep the basic firewall rules but remove only that limitation, you need to use “Custom Rules”. Go to WP Security / Firewall / Custom rules tab and check "Enable Custom .htaccess Rules:". Then put in the custom rules text area:

> `LimitRequestBody 64000000`

That will allow approx. 64 MB uploads. Also make sure that “Place custom rules at the top” checkbox is NOT checked, so it overwrites the 10M limit from above.