# whm Maximum file size allowed for upload: 500 MB

Tags: wordpress, whm

i have a WHM server and i am hosting a website .but not able to upload a file wordpress file  in control panel its says Maximum file size allowed for upload: 500 MB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [increase max upload limit in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751779/increase-max-upload-limit-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Is your wordpress running in PHP? If yes, check the max POST size in php configuration.

Because PHP have a setting wich limit the upload size, no matter what your website defined.

Comment: Yes, we have website working on Wordpress and while uloading file on server showing max lmt 500M but fie size is 900MB how can we increase the size or upload the file?

Comment: our website file size is 900MB but it showing max size can be uploaded only 500MB how to go about it?

Comment: You have to change the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in your php.ini